# Is there a way to derive Lift for "IO a" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, free-monad

For awhile now, whenever people mention the performance hit of free monad + interpreter pattern, I've had this vague idea in my head that: "Why not just use Template Haskell to evaluate your interpreter at compile time? Thus negating the performance hit of free monads entirely, essentially turning the free monad + interpreter pattern into a free monad + compiler pattern."

Making this a little more concrete, let's say I have something like the following:

```
data MyFreeF a = ...
type MyFreeM a = (Free MyFreeF) a

interpret :: MyFreeM a -> IO a
interpret = ...

compileFree :: MyFreeM a -> Q (TExp (IO a))
compileFree m = let x = interpret m in [|| x ||]
```

So, this seems on the surface like it should work. The issue I run into here is that this requires that `Lift` be derived for `IO a`. So my question is: Is such a thing possible? If not, does deriving `Lift` for `IO a` even make sense (i.e. we can't do this today, but if we had X, Y, and Z future GHC extension, we could!)?

So far I have tried using `DeriveLift` for `IO` and its constituent components (Like `State#`) as defined in `GHC.IO`, but was not able to get far.

Comment: I don't think so -- such an instance would have to be able to inspect an `IO` action without running it, which sounds dubious.  I think you could, however, have `interpret` return a `TExp` directly -- essentially just write `interpret` how you would have normally, except quasiquoted.

Comment: @luqui Unfortunately I don't think that is possible in non-trivial cases. That was an approach I tried previously -- GHC stage restrictions get in the way because of the recursive definition of the interpreter.

Comment: that's a good point.  Your compiler is not going to be able to compile an infinitely large program, which is what the recursive definition would get you -- you would have to encode the recursion in some way visible to your compiler.